# Assetics ou Gassetics?

Tags: symfony, assets, dependency-management

I just run on [Gassetics](https://github.com/romanschejbal/gassetic), seems to be the next gen of SF assets management. So far I used Assetics.
One question though : with Assetics I used to split files in order to load only needed one, using Twig parent() method :

```
{% block scripts %}
   {{ parent() }}
   {% javascripts
       '@LCHAdminBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.specific.addition.js'
   %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock scripts %}
```

SO I could add on a specific page, only script needed and so was "forced" (in the noble way) to think and split my twig files accordingly.

Is it possible to do so with Gassetics? I jsut saw that you can specify back-end and front-end files, nothing more.

If I nest Twig files with Gassetic tag, will it do the trick?

**EDIT :** thanks to Wouter J. comment, I adjust my question :
**In Assetics you explicitely specify files you want to include, giving the nesting ability. As in Gassetics you just add the tag which will be replaced during CSS/JS file generation, how do you achieve the same?**

Comment: Both `{% block ... %}` and `{{ parent() }}` are features of Twig. Assetic/Gassetics don't have anything to do with it. (btw, assetic is still perfectly fine for SF assets management, using front-end tools are probably a bit more common these days).

Comment: Thanks for your comment : I understood that it was Twig part, but above code illustrates how to add explicitely one file. I updated my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of this in the gassetic config (see section *yaml example with gassetic.yml* in https://github.com/romanschejbal/gassetic).

Example gassetic.yml:

```
js:
    files:
        common.js:
            - assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js
            - assets/vendor/angular/angular.js
        page1.js:
            - assets/vendor/lchadminbundle/jquery.specific.addition.js
```

common.html.twig:

```
{% block scripts %}
    <!-- prod:common.js --><!-- endbuild -->
{% endblock scripts %}
```

page1.html.twig

```
{% extends 'common.html.twig' %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <!-- prod:page1.js --><!-- endbuild -->
{% endblock scripts %}
```

This approach is better than nesting scripts in children templates, since the commonly needed files can be cached between page requests.

Comment: This answers perfectly my point. Nonetheless, could you explicit a bit yout last sentence? Are you saying that assetics in production mode would produce only one file whereas gassetics would make one per common group, thus allowing caching of this common part?

Comment: Yes, assetic would add your include `jquery.specific.addition.js` to the files included in the parent templates and produce a new file for that page, accessible by `asset_url`.

Gassetic would produce the files `common.js` and `page1.js`. `common.js` is cached.